# How to schedule the job in cron to have run on every month last Saturday?

Tags: unix

I need to schedule the job in cron which should run on every last Saturday of the month.

Answer (score 0):

could you try this;

```
0 0 * * Saturday [ $(date +%d -d '+7 days') -lt '8' ] && yourScript.sh
```

or

```
12 00 * * 6 [ $(date +"\%m") -ne $(date -d 7days +"\%m") ] yourScript.sh
```

5th field, day of week and 6 is saturday)